# Improper integral properies

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable function in every closed and bounded interval.

Assuming $ \int _{0}^{\infty}|f(t)|\,dt \ \ $ exists.

I have to prove that there exists a sequences of $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ so that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty \quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$$

So how do I do that ?

What happen if I only know that $ \int _{0}^{\infty}f(t)\,dt \ \ $is exists and $f$ is continues function

any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what do you mean ? Is this a counterexample ?

Comment: There was an obvious error in the question, which I have corrected. Surely, the $x_n$ are supposed to go to infinity!?

Comment: Here's a hint: What if there is *no* sequence $x_n\to\infty$ with $f(x_n)\to0$? What can you say about the behaviour of $f$ for large $x$ in that case, and how does it affect $\int_0^\infty |f(x)|\,dx$?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thank u !! it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $|f|$ is also integrable.
Let $I_n=\int_0^n|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx$.
By assumption, $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
Therefore $\int_n^{n+1}|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx\to 0$.
Conclude that you can pick a suitable $x_n\in [n,n+1]$.

Comment: Ohh... you mean that because I know that there is an interval at the size of $ \epsilon$ so that $\int_{n}^{n+1}|f(x)|dx$ is in the interval, and because $|f(x)|$ is bounded I can say that for all $x \in [n,n+1] \ $ $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ meaning I can pick $x_n \in [n,n+1] \ $ right ?